# Cant find how to implement django-paypal correctly

Tags: python, django, django-forms, paypal-ipn, django-paypal

I know how the django paypal system is supposed to work. I try to follow the instructions here: https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/standard/ipn.html

My problem is that i dont understand most of it. This is what i have:

views.py

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render
from paypal.standard.forms import PayPalPaymentsForm
from .models import Subs
from .forms import SubForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from forum.views import home
from django.urls import reverse


def BuyShit(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        formbuy = SubForm(request.POST)
        if formbuy.is_valid() and 'buy' in request.POST:
            sub = formbuy.save(commit=False)
            sub.owner = user
            sub.save()
            order_created.delay(sub.id)
            request.session['order_id'] = sub.id
            return redirect(home)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Subs

class SubForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subs

        fields = ('item','price')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from forum.models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Subs(models.Model):
    item = models.Charfield(max_length=55, verbose_name='item')
    price = models.Charfield(max_length=55, verbose_name='item')
    owner = models.Charfield(User, max_length=55, verbose_name='item')
```

I have also added the appropriate settings and url for paypal:

```
 url(r'^paypal/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),
```

On the link to the django-paypal, they have this in views.py:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render
from paypal.standard.forms import PayPalPaymentsForm

def view_that_asks_for_money(request):

    # What you want the button to do.
    paypal_dict = {
        "business": "receiver_email@example.com",
        "amount": "10000000.00",
        "item_name": "name of the item",
        "invoice": "unique-invoice-id",
        "notify_url": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('paypal-ipn')),
        "return": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('your-return-view')),
        "cancel_return": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('your-cancel-view')),
        "custom": "premium_plan",  # Custom command to correlate to some function later (optional)
    }

    # Create the instance.
    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "payment.html", context)
```

Which part of it do i use? where do i add how much it costs or the title?

Then there have a hooks.py thing that i really dont understand how that works:

```
from paypal.standard.models import ST_PP_COMPLETED
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import valid_ipn_received

def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
    ipn_obj = sender
    if ipn_obj.payment_status == ST_PP_COMPLETED:
        # WARNING !
        # Check that the receiver email is the same we previously
        # set on the `business` field. (The user could tamper with
        # that fields on the payment form before it goes to PayPal)
        if ipn_obj.receiver_email != "receiver_email@example.com":
            # Not a valid payment
            return

        # ALSO: for the same reason, you need to check the amount
        # received, `custom` etc. are all what you expect or what
        # is allowed.

        # Undertake some action depending upon `ipn_obj`.
        if ipn_obj.custom == "premium_plan":
            price = ...
        else:
            price = ...

        if ipn_obj.mc_gross == price and ipn_obj.mc_currency == 'USD':
            ...
    else:
        #...

valid_ipn_received.connect(show_me_the_money)
```

All the components seem disconected. I am familiar with django but this seems completely different. 
I am completely lost. And the tutorials online are terrible. Please help!!! I just need to add a button to buy a single product and on success trigger a function to modify the appropriate model. Sounds simple..... Thanks for any help!!!!!